# Why is this not defined if I am importing it?

Tags: python, pygame

So I have a module that creates an instance of a class that is used to bring up the main menu of a pygame game I am making like so:

```
import pygame as pg   #,time, os, csv, operator, sys
import startup, config as C
pg.init()
os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pg.display.set_caption("Tower Defence")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    live_menu = startup.Menu()
```

Then in a separate module called `startup`, I have an event function inside of which has the following line of code:

`live_menu.play_button.event_handler(event)`

`play_button` is an instance variable in the `Menu` class that creates a button class (in another module) which creates a button on the display. `event_handler` is the function that is run to check if the button is pressed.

My issue is that when the line of code above is executed, I get the following error: `NameError: name 'live_menu' is not defined`  despite the fact that i import the module that creates the class. Why is this?

Here is the full [code](https://gist.github.com/bobshaniqua/46614e8e342e1dd7b207782a0ae5ea4a) I have so far. Sorry for the poor amount of comments.

Comment: The statement `live_menu = startup.Menu()` assigns a variable in the current module.  It doesn't affect the `startup` module at all.

Comment: @jasonharper But if i import `main` into the `startup` module, shouldn't i be able to use it?

Comment: No, if __name__ == "__main__" line becomes a success only when you execute main.py and not while you import.

Comment: @gout What would be the best way to resolve this?  I'm not sure at which point in my code i should run the line  `live_menu = startup.Menu()`

And yes that was me trialling things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the line `live_menu = startup.Menu()` is not being executed. This is because you are only importing the file and not executing the file and since the line is inside an `if __name__ == "__main__":` branch, it is not being executed.

**To fix this problem:**

Therefore you can just create a function inside the `main` module and call that function once in the `startup` module.

**main.py**

```
import pygame as pg#, time, os, csv, operator, sys
import startup, config as C
from pygame.locals import *

def start():
    pg.init()
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pg.display.set_caption("Tower Defence")
    print ("Game initialising. Display size: ", C.game_screen_full_w,"x", C.game_screen_h)
    live_menu = startup.Menu()
```

And then in the `startup` module import the file `main` and call the function `start` with the following code.

```
import pygame as pg, os, sys, csv
import config as C, button as B, mapgen, main

main.start()
```

**Update**:

As you have stated in the comments, this alone does not fix the solution because when you import the file `startup` for the class `Menu` in the file `main`, it imports other modules that you don't need and this is causing you bugs.

To fix this define the `Menu` class in a separate file. Call this file something like `Menu.py` and just define the `Menu` class inside it just likr you have with your `Button` class.

In the `main` module, import it using `import menu`.

Making an instance of the class will now look something like this:

`live_menu = menu.Menu()`

**Update 2:**

I just looked at your code again and I see another issue that will arise which is that the `event_main` function will not be defined if you move the `Menu` class out of the `startup` file. The `Menu` class needs this so I think that it would be best to include it as it deals with event handling *only related to the main menu*.

I just changed the code so that it will work as a method. Here is the full class.

```
class Menu():
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = C.screen #importing screen from config file
        self.button_x = C.game_screen_full_w * 0.4
        self.button_y = [C.game_screen_h * 0.30, C.game_screen_h * 0.50, C.game_screen_h * 0.70]
        #create 4 buttons on screen
        self.play_button = B.Button("mapgen.main()", (160, 40), (self.button_x,self.button_y[0]), C.L_BLUE, C.DARK_GREY, None, C.BLUE, C.L_BLUE, "Play")
        self.lead_button = B.Button("startup.Lead()", (200, 40), (self.button_x - 20,self.button_y[1]), C.L_BLUE, C.DARK_GREY, None, C.BLUE, C.L_BLUE, "Leaderboard")
        self.quit_button = B.Button("quit()", (160, 40), (self.button_x,self.button_y[2]), C.L_BLUE, C.DARK_GREY, None, C.BLUE, C.L_BLUE, "Quit")
        self.vol_button = B.Button(None, (50,50), (40,40), C.L_BLUE, C.DARK_GREY, None, C.BLUE, C.L_BLUE, "♫")
        self.menu_screen()

    def menu_screen(self):
        m_loop = False
        self.screen.fill(C.BLUE)
        while not m_loop:
            self.play_button.draw()
            self.lead_button.draw()
            self.quit_button.draw()
            self.vol_button.draw()
            self.event_main()
            pg.display.update()


    def event_main():
        for event in pg.event.get():
            self.play_button.event_handler(event)
            self.lead_button.event_handler(event)
            self.quit_button.event_handler(event)
            self.vol_button.event_handler(event)
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit(); sys.exit()
```

I think that this is the last issue with the code.

**Note:** I changed the line `pg.quit(), sys.exit()` to `pg.quit(); sys.exit()`. As far as I know you cannot delimit statements in Python with the comma. I am sure that you can with the semicolon though.

Hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the method with the `start` function but it results in both the files needing to import each other which doesn't like to work. 
Running `main.py `causes startup to be imported which then runs the `start`function in` main.py` and throws back an error saying `module startup has no attribute Menu`. 

Running `startup.py` first doesn't work because it has to import `main` which in turn imports `startup` again and throws out a similar error.

Could you perhaps clarify a bit more specifically on how it's meant to work?

Comment: If i screwed up getting my point across: the main idea of what i want to happen is to have a module that creates an instance of the class `Menu`, which i can then access in the same module as the one that contains the class `Menu`. If it's better to ditch that idea and keep it all in one file then that might be what i'll have to do.

Comment: Ok I see the issue. What you should do (and what I should have originally included the answer) is to define the `Menu` class in a seperate file altogether. This makes more sense so that you can import the class without importing a file that runs a load of other modules. Just define the class and do not import from `main` in the file, update the imports and everything should work ok.

Comment: @J.Shaw I have just updated my answer twice to fix the issue that you have pointed out and an issue that I foresaw when looking at your code. I hope that these two updates will solve your problem!

Comment: Nice! I got it to work. Thank you very much for your help :D

Comment: Glad I could help you!